# Trying to read data from a file and tokenize it in c using strtok() and fgets()

Tags: c, file, segmentation-fault, strtok

I'm attempting to read data from a textfile using fgets(), tokenize it using the "|" delimiter and store the results in an array called "menuresult[]". So far, it's failing. It gives me a segfault, and valgrind seems to think it's because of the "strdup" line. I've run out of ideas. Any help would be appreciated. Here's my code so far:

```
   FILE *menufile = fopen("menu.dat", "r");  
   char *menuresult[1024];

   while((fgets(line, sizeof(line), menufile)) != NULL) {   

       if (i == 0) {
          token = strtok(line, "|");
          menuresult[i] = strdup(token);
          }

       else {

          token = strtok(NULL, "|"); 
          menuresult[i] = strdup(token);
          }
          i++;      
       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about this: when you reached the end of line, you are passing a `NULL` to `strdup`, it causes undefined behavior. You need a loop to parse every line of the file like this:

```
while((fgets(line, sizeof(line), menufile)) != NULL) {   
      token = strtok(line, "|");
      menuresult[i] = strdup(token);
      printf("%s\n", menuresult[i]);
      i++;
      while(token){
          token = strtok(NULL, "|");
          if(token)
          {
              menuresult[i] = strdup(token);
              printf("%s\n", menuresult[i]);
          }
          i++;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you may need these changes-

```
   FILE *menufile = fopen("menu.dat", "r");  
   char *menuresult[1024];

   while((fgets(line, sizeof(line), menufile)) != NULL) {   

          while((token = strtok(line, "|")) != NULL){

          menuresult[i] = strdup(token);

          i++;
          }              
       }
```

Comment: @Sathish. Thanks, but I changed it to use malloc() and still get the segfault.

Comment: @Sathish. I'm checking the return of strtok using this code, but still getting the segfault.

Answer (score 0):

Your not checking the return of strtok which can return null, plus your replacing line in the while loop, strtok internally keeps track of the string which is why you pass in a null, you prob need a double while loop?

```
while read file
    while strtok != null
```

Comment: Just tried to check the return of strtok using "while(((fgets(line, sizeof(line), menufile)) != NULL) && (strtok != NULL))". Still get the segfault.

Comment: there was a second part to my answer, my C is rusty so I had to look up strtok and it is an iterative method that internally holds the string you first passed. the second time through you tell it to use the string you passed in the first time, but you've already replaced it with a new one. strok need to be in its own while loop: **sathish** posted n example pf what I was talking about

Comment: So does that mean I need a separate while loop to read the contents of the file into a string, and a separate one to tokenize the string?

Comment: This is where learning to use a debugger would save you much frustration.I'm willing to bet the token you passing to the second call to strdup is garbage and not null terminated which is causing the segfault. What platform are you on?

Comment: sathish's example was a step in the right direction for sure. jfly's example did the trick. I'll have to study it to see how it works. Thanks.

Comment: I'm on Debian Linux, using GCC. I've used GDB occasionally. I find it a bit arcane to be honest. Presumably I would have to step through the code and watch the values that I'm passing to strdup?

Comment: yes, gdb, is a tough one to use, I havnt used linux for  a long time, probably 11 years. Anyway, I'm sure you have a graphical environment and both gtk and kde both had a debugger back then. Really if your interested in programming **youll spend as much if not more time in a debugger than writing code**, so get used to it :) If you had used one, a watch set on token would have shown garbage after the call to strtok and you would have realized something was wrong there. Then a quick google for an example of strtok would have shown that you had to loop a second time to get the tokens from line

Comment: Wise words Steve. Yep, I'm using Xfce, and I'm pretty sure I've got a GUI for GDB. I think I'm going to get into learning how to use GDB, I'm sure it will save me a lot of time in the long run.